# Getting error " {"message":"Unauthorized"}" in api gateway with custom authorizer

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created a api gateway method and deployed it. after it i have created a custom authorizer and bind it with api gateway method. When i call the api gateway method through custom domain link then i am getting the **{"message":"Unauthorized"}** error. If I test custom authorizer by it's tool then it works fine.

If i call without custom authorizer by using custom domain then it works fine. I have also checked the api gateway log but no logs are creating if call api with custom authorizer.

I am using below lambda node js script for custom authorizer -

---

`

```
console.log('Loading function');
exports.handler =  (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("event = "+event);
    console.log("token = "+event.authorizationToken);
    console.log("method = "+event.methodArn);
    var token = event.authorizationToken;
    // Call oauth provider, crack jwt token, etc.
    // In this example, the token is treated as the status for simplicity.

    switch (token.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'allow':
            callback(null, generatePolicy('user', 'Allow', event.methodArn));
            break;
        case 'deny':
            callback(null, generatePolicy('user', 'Deny', event.methodArn));
            break;
        case 'unauthorized':
            callback("Unauthorized");   // Return a 401 Unauthorized response
            break;
        default:
            callback("Error: Invalid token"); 
    }
};

var generatePolicy = function(principalId, effect, resource) {
    var authResponse = {};

    authResponse.principalId = principalId;
    if (effect && resource) {
        var policyDocument = {};
        policyDocument.Version = '2012-10-17'; // default version
        policyDocument.Statement = [];
        var statementOne = {};
        statementOne.Action = 'execute-api:Invoke'; // default action
        statementOne.Effect = effect;
        statementOne.Resource = resource;
        policyDocument.Statement[0] = statementOne;
        authResponse.policyDocument = policyDocument;
    }

    // Can optionally return a context object of your choosing.
    authResponse.context = {};
    authResponse.context.stringKey = "stringval";
    authResponse.context.numberKey = 123;
    authResponse.context.booleanKey = true;
    return authResponse;
}
```

`

---

In header i am passing below parameters -

```
'type: TOKEN',
    'authorizationToken: allow',
    'methodArn: arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:accountId:app_id/*/GET/users/*'
```

---

So please tell me that where am i doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please also include your authorizer setting on API Gateway side and the request to API Gateway.

Comment: @KaHouIeong I am not much aware about api gateway. could you tell me where need to include authorizer setting in api gateway